# Установка драйвера AMD на Linux после обновления ядра

Tags: linux, linux-mint, драйвер, amd, radeon

Обновил ядро Linux до 3.7.1 и перестал работать драйвер видеокарты. Видеодрайвера теперь вообще никакого нет, даже свободного (хотя какой-то Radeon в Additional Drivers присутствует), и даже "Информация о системе" при выборе вкладки OpenGL пишет, что не может его инициализировать.

Пробовал его поставить через программу Additional Drivers, но он написал, что не может его установить и послал смотреть jockey.log. Я открыл, а он большой и в нём много всего лишнего (что-то про NVidia даже было, непонятно откуда), и непонятно, где искать ошибку.

Пробовал установить из скачанного с сайта AMD. Установщик пожаловался на отсутствие заголовочных файлов Linux 3.7.1, хотя они были установлены. Но version.h, который он искал и в самом деле не существует. Я взял version.h от старого ядра и скопировал туда, поменяв число на текущую версию. Драйвер установился, но написал, что были какие-то непонятные ошибки. Так ничего и не заработало. Только Catalyst Control Center появился, но с каким-то непонятным широким шрифтом.

Использую Linux Mint 13 KDE x64.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте удалить сначала version.h, который скопировали. Потом установите исходники от текушего ядра и сконфигурите его с текушим конфигом(его можно взять в /boot). Установите dkms для того чтобы потом при обновлении ядра драйвера пересобирались сами. После этого удалите драйвера(этот скрипт может помочь для полного удаления http://paste.ubuntu.com/1322981/) и поставьте по новой.

Comment: >Потом установите исходники от текушего ядра и сконфигурите его с текушим конфигом А как это сделать? Просто я пока только начинающий в Linux'е. Перекомпилировать ядро нужно что ли?>Установите dkms для того чтобы потом при обновлении ядра драйвера пересобирались сами. Менеджер программ показывает, что dkms уже установлен.